Amazon Route53 HTTPS DNS Record support
Is there a way to add "HTTPS" DNS Record using Amazon Route53?
RFC 9460 - Service Binding and Parameter Specification via the DNS (SVCB and HTTPS Resource Records)
If not, is this something on AWS's pipeline to support soon?

On October 30, 2024, Amazon announced support for HTTPS, SSHFP, SVCB, and TLSA DNS resource records
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2024/10/amazon-route-53-https-sshfp-svcb-tlsa-dns-support/
